# How to make a div take up space even if it is empty?

Tags: html, css

I have two images wrapped in divs, one with caption while another without:

```
<div class="figure">
  <a href="https://a248.e.akamai.net/assets.github.com/images/modules/footer/blacktocat.svg"><img src="https://a248.e.akamai.net/assets.github.com/images/modules/footer/blacktocat.svg" height="100px" /></a>
  <div class="caption">title</div>
</div>

<div class="figure">
  <a href="https://a248.e.akamai.net/assets.github.com/images/modules/footer/blacktocat.svg"><img src="https://a248.e.akamai.net/assets.github.com/images/modules/footer/blacktocat.svg" height="100px" /></a>
 <div class="caption"></div>
</div>
```

And corresponding css is as follows:

```
.figure {
    display: inline-block;
}
.figure a {
    display: block;
}
.figure .caption {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    height: 22px;
}
```

My problem is that even I have assigned height attribute to caption div, it still takes up no space, as a result tops of images are not aligned. Is there any fix to this? The problem code is also available at http://cssdesk.com/cF7G9.

Comment: btw. `height="100px"` is wrong! `height="100"` or `style="height: 100px;"` would be correct!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add:

```
.figure {
    vertical-align: top
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**You should avoid using inline-block because EI7 and older do not support it.**

```
.figure {
    float: left;
    width:100px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.figure a {
    display: block;
}
.figure .caption {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    height: 22px;
}
```

For any block containers, set a specific width and `float: left` and they will line up like a charm.

As you can see here : http://jsfiddle.net/zalun/E4mz9/

Comment: You can use `display: inline-block` in IE6 and IE7, but only on elements that do not have `display: block` specified by default. For example, it will work with a `<span />`, but not a `<div />`

Answer (score 2):

The top divs don't align because you have `display: block` elements inside `display: inline-block`. They are "spilling over".

I got a solution here which clamps the width of the contained block elements by shrink wrapping (absolute positioning): http://cssdesk.com/jAV8S

```
.figure {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 120px;
    width: 130px;
    background: green;
    position: relative;
}
.figure .caption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this solves the problem, but min-height and min-width might work.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the div put `&nbsp;` This will insert a space. When there is absolutely no content inside a element, some browsers will not allow it to take up any space, horizontally or vertically.

Answer (score 0):

Add width to the div.
now that its only height, The browser doesn't know big it should be so its high but 0px wide

Answer (score 0):

Add a `float:left;` to `.figure`and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not the height of the div [that is set correctly - try giving it a background color] but the height of its container. All you need to fix is:

```
.figure {
height: 100px [etc]
}
```